# 404 on Laravel Dusk pipelines testing

Tags: php, laravel

**Situation:** Bitucket pipelines test fails for this test only (out of 35 tests of varying content), and it only fails in the Bitbucket pipeline. The test does not fail locally. The test fails because the endpoint /account/create cannot be reached during the test, navigating to this endpoint without post data will render a 404. as there is no data to validate and no view to be rendered.

**Expected behaviour:** End point creates the record and redirects to the default page, or, end point fails validation and returns validation errors (422)

**Actual behaviour:**

- **Local test:** End point creates the record or validation fails, as
  expected
- **Bitbucket pipelines dusk test:** 404 error on form submission.

The view

```html
<form onsubmit="disableButton()" action="{{ $actionRoute }}" method="POST" class="tenant-creation">
    // the form
    <input type="submit" value="{{ $button }}" class="button" id="createButton"/>
</form>
```

The controller that serves the view. There are different view parameters for create and edit which can be served here. This is for creation.

```php
// AccountsController.php

public function add(Request $request) {

    return view('master.accountSettings', [
        // other array items
        'actionRoute' => route('master.accounts.create'),
        'button' => 'Create',
    ]);
}

public function create(Request $request) {
    // Handles the form
    // Returns Validation 422 response, or can redirect to '/'
    // Does not return a 404 status code
}
```

The route

```php
// web.php

    Route::post('/account/create', 'Master\AccountsController@create')
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->name('master.accounts.create');
```